# Slow queries on catalogsearch_query

Tags: mysql, catalogsearch, search, query

I have a site with approx 6500 products. The are constantly running into problems where they run up against the hosting companies PHP Process limit.

I have been running a SQL profiler against their site today and came up with the following slow queries:

SLOWEST: UPDATE `catalogsearch_query` SET `is_processed` = '0' (13s)

The next slow query is the actual search on the catalog search query table. (78,000 rows)

[image]

My question: Can I truncate this table?

Here are all the queries by threads during the day in order of slowness

[image]

Comment: Yes - this is a terrible query.  Ran into this issue on EE 1.14.1 - I did two things that significantly improved performance.  First, make is_processed an index.  Second, change the query so that only rows in which is_processed !=0 rather than doing a full scan.  The query should be: `getTable('catalogsearch/search_query'),
    array('is_processed' => 0), array('is_processed != 0'))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the table responsible for the list of search queries made on your site. It can be truncated, but you lose all of the historical data.

I think there's another underlying problem here. 78K should only take a few milliseconds perform a `SELECT`. Even with a full-column select statement, as you are doing in the screenshot, it should be very quick.

Perhaps you have an extension or a program that works on this table? Or too many cron jobs? Try running `SHOW PROCESSLIST;` and see what kind of database operations are going on when it's slow.

Comment: I have been running a profiler against the database all day today. It tell me the the slow processes... I am not sure how that will help me with this query? I added the queries ordered by slowness